# Red Hat subscriptions in EC2 via AWS - are they just for specific AMIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat

So the docs say that if you launch a Red Hat image in AWS then you will be charged a fee for the Red Hat subscription but all of the billing will be done via AWS.

I used packer to bake a new AMI based on RHEL 7.7 with extra hardening but on any instance I launch with my new AMI, yum can't retrieve packages because it's not subscribed. Does AWS just know which instances are using the Red Hat provided community packages and allow access to their RHN repos that way? And therefore for images that I bake based on them, will I have to sort out subscriptions separately? Or is there a way to use the same subscription system?

Eventually I imagine these instances will subscribe separately via Red Hat Cloud Access anyway but I'm just interested to know if there's some weird magic under the hood in AWS or if I've maybe broken my PKI client certs for RHN.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your issue using the RHEL 7.2 image in Marketplace.  Are you using a local version of RHEL and creating an AMI out of it or are you using a  Marketplace image of RHEL?

Comment: Hmm interesting. I'm using the community image of 7.7 provided by Red Hat

Comment: Oop, I found it - Billing Product Code. - https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/4922